# Advice on how to update navigation code to hide and show hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a list with one particular link that hides/shows a hidden div. As a link is clicked the class 'active' is removed and added and the hidden div checked to see whether it is visible or hidden and hidden/shown accordingly. This all works ok, but, there is one problem. When I click Square I want to show the #square but when I click it again I want to hide the #square but because Im checking for the .active this cant be done. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can update the code so this can be achieved?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var square = $('#square'),
        test = $('#test');

    square.hide();

    test.find('a').on('click', function(e){

        if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){


            if ( square.is(':visible') ){
              square.hide();
            }

            var id = $(this).data('id');

            test.find('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            if( id === 'square' ){
              square.show();
            }

        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });        

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="test">
<li><a href="#">Triangle</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-id="square">Square</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Circle</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="square"></div>​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xBuUY/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? There are many ways you can toggle the `#square` div, but without knowing what you're trying to do it'll be hard to guess exactly what you're trying to do. For instance, you can just test the id and do the toggle before testing for the class: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBuUY/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [a fork](http://jsfiddle.net/drublic/Wd5Ha/2/) of your Fiddle.
I've moved the block for testing whether the square should be visible or not outside of checking which link should be active. The `#square` is toggled and not only shown which garanties that it's hidden when it's already active. Just test the Fiddle.

Apart from that I optimized the event-handler: It now uses delegation, which is faster than just the link handler on each of the links. Bubbling of the links is prevented by `e.stopPropagation()`. I've added this before any other methods or anything else is called for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Move this block of code --
            if ( square.is(':visible') ){
              square.hide();
            }
outside of the hasClass('active') check.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be simplified, you're wanting to toggle `square` regardless of class, so I've removed the `square` toggle outside of the class test. Try this Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xBuUY/2/)